# Android: how to open an apk file after downloading for auto-update?

Tags: android

I have an application that I'd like to add auto-update functionality (it's not in the marketplace).  I have all the code in place that would check to see if there is an update available and then I call something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW ,Uri.parse(Configuration.APK_URL));
c.startActivity(intent);
```

which starts downloading the file. Is there a way that I can programmatically tell it to "open" the file to begin the installation process without the user having to go to the downloads and clicking on it?

Answer (score 13):

The answer above was for pre-API-24.

If your app targets API 24 or more (and it should), you need to use something else (otherwise you get FileUriExposedException, as described [**here**](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en)) :

```
    File apkFile = new File(...);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri fileUri = android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", apkFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(intent);
```

provider_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>-->
    <external-path path="Android/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME" name="files_root" />
    <external-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />
</paths>
```

where YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME is your app's package name.

manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />


<provider
  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Comment: I followed this approach but when downloading is finished nothing happens

Comment: Not related to downloading. You need to do this on the file path.

Comment: I do that after downloading is finished and I use the file path but nothing happens :||

Comment: @hosseinAmini Perhaps you are missing this in the manifest:     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

Comment: You are right it was because of the missing the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission, thank you

Comment: @hosseinAmini It was added after I wrote the answer, so I've updated my answer when I noticed it's missing and you told me about it.

Answer (score 7):

This will start the installation process

```
File apkFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/packageName.apk");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This won't work anymore, if your app targets API 24 or more. See my answer below