# Parsing Error on downloading and running an .apk file

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-download-manager, download-manager

I have a feature in my app which allows the user to download a new version.
But my problem is when I start the intent which should start the installation proccess there is a message:

> Parse error. There was a problem parsing the package

This is my code

```
Button button;
String urlApp = "example.com/app.apk"
String fileName = "app.apk";
DownloadManager downloadManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            File file = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
            if (file.exists()){
                boolean deleted = file.delete();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlApp));
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setTitle("Click to update");
            downloadManager.enqueue(request);
            registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

        }
    });

}

private void openFile() {
    Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/"+fileName)),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(install);
}

BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        openFile();
    }
};

}
```

It's just for .apk files, .txt files work fine. There is neither a error on the logcat.
The deleting is also not working but this isn't my primary problem.

Thanks in advance :D

Sorry if this is a stupid problem but this is my first time working with the download manager

Comment: This is all so weird... The Google Play Store handles the updates for you. So, why using a different, custom, unreliable method?

Comment: Sure I could do that, but I want to do it by myself

Comment: For sure it can be a great exercise. But also a great waste of time, if you mean to be productive!

Comment: I'm doing this just for fun so my focus isn't that much on productivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i finally solved it

Instead of:

```
install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+"/"+fileName)),
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

i used

```
    install.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/"+fileName)),
            "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error as you OP. But this answer doesn't really help becaise in newer versions of Android, you can't use the `getExternalStorage...` approach. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40936215/2583765.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across the same problem earlier.

Please check the Min API level for your new Application version and the API level of the device you are using.

Comment: The minSdkVersion is 19, the targetSdkVersion is 23 and my device is also skdVersion 23