# Java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: when I try to launch my application with apk on another device

Tags: java, android, apk

I'm writing an application in Android with Firebase, and everything works, 0 errors, 0 warning.
Everything works until I don't generate a signed apk.
When I do that, and I try to send the app to my boss, the app once installed crashes.
Firebase crash reporting says that the error is:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.archimedia.moveng.Bambooz: java.lang.RuntimeException: Something went wrong, please report to [REDACTED_EMAIL_ADDRESS]
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4861)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:178)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1531)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5637)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:960)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:755)
arrow_drop_down


Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Something went wrong, please report to [REDACTED_EMAIL_ADDRESS]
com.a.a.c.a.a ()
com.a.a.a.a ()
com.archimedia.moveng.Bambooz.onCreate ()
android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1017)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4858)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:178)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1531)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5637)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:960)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:755)
arrow_drop_down



Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context]
java.lang.Class.getConstructor (Class.java:531)
java.lang.Class.getConstructor (Class.java:495)
com.a.a.c.a.a ()
com.a.a.a.a ()
com.archimedia.moveng.Bambooz.onCreate ()
android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1017)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4858)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:178)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1531)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5637)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:960)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

My Bambooz.java it's just this:

```
public class Bambooz extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay probably you need to update SHA1 certificat from releases apk using keystore.jks file in firebase console for your application.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have just checked if there was an error on sha1 but the key it's the same that I've inserted before... where am I wrong?

Comment: If you've shared a signed APK, you should check Proguard rules if they need to be changed. If you've shared a non-signed APK, make sure instant-run is turned off, otherwise you will get issues running: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42494382/878126

Comment: I've shared signed apk, my only edit to that file was to ignore DOMImplementationRegistry.
Is there any connection between them?