# How to install Android apk from code in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-intent

I found snippet for Java. How can I write such a code in C# Unity?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("link to downloaded file")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I can't see any detailed troubles in your description. From first glace I would say this code should work in C#.

Comment: My point was that you need to add as much details in your description as possible. As c# developer I can't see any problems in this code - it should work in c#. You should add notes that c# Unity framework do not have these classes and you suppose you should use `AndroidJavaObject` and `AndroidJavaClass` to achieve same behaviour. :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can build a jar/aar plugin and call it from C#. That's more easier to do.

Another solution is to use `AndroidJavaObject` and `AndroidJavaClass`  to do this directly without a plugin. Doing it with `AndroidJavaObject` and `AndroidJavaClass` requires lots of testing to get it right. Below is what I use to do that. It downloads an APK then installs it.

First of all create a UI text called **"TextDebug"** so it you will see what's going on during the download/install. If you don't do this you must comment out or remove all the `GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text...` line of code.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(downLoadFromServer());
}

IEnumerator downLoadFromServer()
{
    string url = "http://apkdl.androidapp.baidu.com/public/uploads/store_2/f/f/a/ffaca37aaaa481003d74725273c98122.apk?xcode=854e44a4b7e568a02e713d7b0af430a9136d9c32afca4339&filename=unity-remote-4.apk";


    string savePath = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "data");
    savePath = Path.Combine(savePath, "AntiOvr.apk");

    Dictionary<string, string> header = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";
    header.Add("User-Agent", userAgent);
    WWW www = new WWW(url, null, header);


    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        //Must yield below/wait for a frame
        GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Stat: " + www.progress;
        yield return null;
    }

    byte[] yourBytes = www.bytes;

    GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Done downloading. Size: " + yourBytes.Length;


    //Create Directory if it does not exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(savePath)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(savePath));
        GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Created Dir";
    }

    try
    {
        //Now Save it
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, yourBytes);
        Debug.Log("Saved Data to: " + savePath.Replace("/", "\\"));
        GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Saved Data";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Failed To Save Data to: " + savePath.Replace("/", "\\"));
        Debug.LogWarning("Error: " + e.Message);
        GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Error Saving Data";
    }

    //Install APK
    installApp(savePath);
}

public bool installApp(string apkPath)
{
    try
    {
        AndroidJavaClass intentObj = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
        string ACTION_VIEW = intentObj.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW");
        int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = intentObj.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK");
        AndroidJavaObject intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", ACTION_VIEW);

        AndroidJavaObject fileObj = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", apkPath);
        AndroidJavaClass uriObj = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
        AndroidJavaObject uri = uriObj.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("fromFile", fileObj);

        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setDataAndType", uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setClassName", "com.android.packageinstaller", "com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity");

        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intent);

        GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Success";
        return true;
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Error: " + e.Message;
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

For **Android API 24** and above, this requires a different code since the API changed. The C# code below is based on the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40936215/3785314) Java answer.

```
//For API 24 and above
private bool installApp(string apkPath)
{
    bool success = true;
    GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Installing App";

    try
    {
        //Get Activity then Context
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaObject unityContext = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

        //Get the package Name
        string packageName = unityContext.Call<string>("getPackageName");
        string authority = packageName + ".fileprovider";

        AndroidJavaClass intentObj = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
        string ACTION_VIEW = intentObj.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW");
        AndroidJavaObject intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", ACTION_VIEW);


        int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = intentObj.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK");
        int FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION = intentObj.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION");

        //File fileObj = new File(String pathname);
        AndroidJavaObject fileObj = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", apkPath);
        //FileProvider object that will be used to call it static function
        AndroidJavaClass fileProvider = new AndroidJavaClass("android.support.v4.content.FileProvider");
        //getUriForFile(Context context, String authority, File file)
        AndroidJavaObject uri = fileProvider.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getUriForFile", unityContext, authority, fileObj);

        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setDataAndType", uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intent);

        GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Success";
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        GameObject.Find("TextDebug").GetComponent<Text>().text = "Error: " + e.Message;
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you get the Exception:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser
>   android.content.pm.packageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.c‌​ontent.pm.PackageMan‌​ager.java.lang.Strin‌​g)'

You have to do few things.

**1**.Copy "android-support-v4.jar" from your **"AndroidSDK/extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar"**
 directory to your **"UnityProject/Assets/Plugins/Android"** directory.

**2**.Create a file called "AndroidManifest.xml" in your **UnityProject/Assets/Plugins/Android** directory and put the code below into it.

**Make sure to replace *"com.company.product"* with your own package name**. There are **2** instances where this appeared. You must replace both of them:

These are found in *package="com.company.product"* and *android:authorities="com.company.product.fileprovider"*. Don't change or remove the *"fileprovider"* and don't change anything else.

Here is the "AndroidManifest.xml" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.product" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>

    <provider
          android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
          android:authorities="com.company.product.fileprovider"
          android:exported="false"
          android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>

  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>
```

**3**.Create a new file called "*provider_paths.xml*" in your **"UnityProject/Assets/Plugins/Android/res/xml"** directory and put the code below in it. As you can see, you have to create a *res* and then an *xml* folder.

**Make sure to replace *"com.company.product"* with your own package name**. 
It only appeared **once**.

Here is what you should put into this "*provider_paths.xml*" file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!--<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>-->
  <external-path path="Android/data/com.company.product" name="files_root" />
  <external-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />
</paths>
```

Comment: android-support.v4.jar is in a different place, now-a-days.  Here's a quick video on how to get it.  https://youtu.be/E8iKrGaKITQ

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add an update to the fantastic answer given by @Programmer, to reflect changes to the Android SDK and Unity. I hope it can be useful to someone else. I am working with SDK version 26 and Unity 2017.3.1. I am new to almost all of this so please do correct me if I've missed or misunderstood anything!

1. The android-support-v4.jar (used to get the FileProvider class) is no longer available. For versions up to 24.1.1 it is located at **Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4\24.1.1** but for versions after that you must instead use support-core-utils at **Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-core-utils**. Instead of a jar file use the relevant .aar file and drag that into a Plugins folder in your Unity project.
2. You need to add android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES to your AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.productsomethingelse" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
     <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
     <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
       <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
         <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
         <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
       </activity>

       <provider
             android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
             android:authorities="com.company.product.fileprovider"
             android:exported="false"
             android:grantUriPermissions="true">
         <meta-data
             android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
             android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
       </provider>

     </application>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="24" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
   </manifest>
   ```

   Note that I've also changed the first instance of **com.company.product** to **com.company.productsomethingelse**
3. That should now build ok and work, although during the build process
   Unity is giving the warning **OBSOLETE - Providing Android resources
   in Assets/Plugins/Android/res is deprecated, please move your
   resources to an AAR or an Android Library.**. To get round this
   create a new zip file and put your AndroidManifest.xml at the top
   level of the zip. Then add the provider_paths.xml detailed by
   @Programmer into the zip in the folder structure
   **res/xml/provider_paths.xml**. Rename the zip to give it a .aar file extension and then drag it into your Unity project
   Assets/Plugins folder. The reason I changed the AndroidManifest.xml entry to **com.company.productsomethingelse** is that when I used **com.company.product** the Unity build process was throwing up a naming conflict. I think because the manifest is now in a separate aar it needs to have a distinct package name.

Answer (score 3):

With later versions of Unity, it gets a bit more complicated. `Assets/Plugins/Android/res` got deprecated. And with Android 9.0 `android.support.v4` got merged into `androidx.core` and everything got renamed and moved around. Fortunately Unity is a bit better about supporting Android plugins now, so with this solution **you no longer have to add any jar or aar to your project**.

Note that Android has a bunch of nag screens associated with this install process. There's a one-time accept screen for untrusted builds per app, and if you have google play on the device, play protect adds a bunch of screens that make your app look like malware. (Which is a good thing, as you should only be doing this stuff on kiosk-mode style devices you own, where you can turn off Play Protect.)

Adding to [Programmer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012767/4093018). In Unity 2019 and 2020, you can compile a plugin directly in Unity, and you no longer need the jar file. In 2019, it needs to be in `Assets/Plugins/Android` and have a couple extra files. In 2020, the folder just needs the suffix `.androidlib` and can be located anywhere in `Assets/`.

```
package.androidlib
  src
    main
      res
        xml
          provider_paths.xml
      AndroidManifest.xml
  build.gradle
  AndroidManifest.xml  (only for 2019)
  project.properties  (only for 2019)
```

**provider_paths.xml:** As explained by Programmer.

**AndroidManifest.xml:** is mainly there to give this new library a bundle ID. This should not match any other IDs; it can be anything and usually it's `com.companyname.packagename`. Note that it's within the `main/` folder

We can also do the rest of the AndroidManifest.xml stuff here, because all AndroidManifest.xml files will get merged in the final APK nowadays. The FileProvider package has changed to `androidx.core.content.FileProvider`.

I've noticed you need `android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`; but I'm not sure whether you need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE like Kaushix suggests. (Maybe on certain devices? I think this is covered by Project Settings->Write Permission.)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.anything.anythingelse">
    <application>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle:** This should probably match your project target and min SDK version. It's OK if it's less, but target needs to be at least 28 to use androidx.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
}
```

For 2019, the extra AndroidManifest.xml and project.properties files purely exist to tell Unity to build this folder. In 2020, Unity's smart enough to not need them.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- This extra manifest, as well as project.properties in this folder shouldn't be necessary with the newer gradle project format. Can remove if you upgrade to 2020.1. -->
</manifest>
```

**project.properties:**

```
android.library=true
```

**AndroidPostProcess.cs:**

We also need an editor script to enable AndroidX support in the main gradle file, and turn on Jetifier, which should fix any other plugins compiled against the old android.support libraries.

```
using UnityEditor.Android;

public class AndroidPostProcess : IPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject
{
    public int callbackOrder => 0;
    public void OnPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject(string path)
    {
        string gradlePropertiesPath = path + "/gradle.properties";
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(gradlePropertiesPath);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            if (line.Contains("android.useAndroidX"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (line.Contains("android.enableJetifier"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            builder.AppendLine(line);
        }
        builder.AppendLine("android.useAndroidX=true");
        builder.AppendLine("android.enableJetifier=true");
        File.WriteAllText(gradlePropertiesPath, builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I would kill for a simple project with all this working.   I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException: androidx.core.content.FileProvider .  Probably AndroidPostProcess not being executed correctly

Comment: I don't have a simple project with it working, but one thing that helped is looking at the actual output, which will be somewhere in Temp/ while you keep unity open. If you can't find it, try printing the path parameter to `OnPostGenerateGradleAndroidProject(string path)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here we have to change your manifest file. We have to give **Read & Write permissions**.
after change this we can easily install downloaded application file.

Without these permissions we can't access Android External Files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.company.product" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1">
      <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
      <application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
          <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>

        <provider
              android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
              android:authorities="com.company.product.fileprovider"
              android:exported="false"
              android:grantUriPermissions="true">
          <meta-data
              android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
              android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

      </application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"   android:maxSdkVersion="29"  />
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

After all these great answers I still had an issue: App immidiatly closes on start.
In my case adding the Fileprovider code to the manifest causes this issue.

Fix:
I manually added the androidx.core library to the Unity Project.

1. Download the library (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.core/core/1.0.1)
2. Copy the aar-file into the folder "Assets\Plugins\Android\libs"
3. In Unity click on the aar- file and check the "Android" Checkmark

I'm still finding some other issues, but at least the app starts now.
Maybe i could help someone else with this Information

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully implemented this recently. @Programmer's answer helped me a lot. but there is some more step required in order to work this perfectly.

### Firstly:

`REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` is required so add this in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

### Then replace this line:

```
AndroidJavaClass fileProvider = new AndroidJavaClass("android.support.v4.content.FileProvider");
```

### With:

```
AndroidJavaClass fileProvider = new AndroidJavaClass("androidx.core.content.FileProvider");
```

Here we don't need to download/move any jar file.

### Lastly replace the provider code in `AndroidManifest.xml` with:

```
<provider
  android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="com.company.product.fileprovider"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

If everything works right, there will be default popup asking for the permission to install the app.