# How to convert from Uri.fromfile to FileProvider.getUriForFile in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-fileprovider

I have a code from [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012767/3785314) answer code in unity to install an apk but it does not work in Android 7.0 because `Uri.fromfile` is no longer supported and `FileProvider.getUriForFile` should now be used.

I tried opening the project in android studio and followed this tutorial to manipulate the manifest file - https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en

```
        AndroidJavaClass intentObj = new 
        AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
        string ACTION_VIEW = intentObj.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW");
        int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = intentObj.GetStatic<int>
        ("FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK");
        AndroidJavaObject intent = new 
        AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", ACTION_VIEW);

        AndroidJavaObject fileObj = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", 
        apkPath);
        AndroidJavaClass uriObj = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
        AndroidJavaObject uri = uriObj.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>
        ("fromFile", fileObj);

        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setDataAndType", uri, 
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setClassName", 
        "com.android.packageinstaller", 
        "com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity");

        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new 
        AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = 
        unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace

```
AndroidJavaObject fileObj = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", apkPath);
AndroidJavaClass uriObj = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
AndroidJavaObject uri = uriObj.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("fromFile", fileObj);
```

with

```
AndroidJavaObject fileObj = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", apkPath);
AndroidJavaClass fileProvider = new AndroidJavaClass("android.support.v4.content.FileProvider");
AndroidJavaObject uri = fileProvider.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getUriForFile", unityContext, authority, fileObj);
```

The `authority` parameter is constructed with:

```
string packageName = unityContext.Call<string>("getPackageName");
string authority = packageName + ".fileprovider";
```

Then add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` permission to the intent before calling `currentActivity.Call` function.

```
intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

For the complete script see the now edited [**How to install Android apk from unity application**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012767/3785314) question.