# Installing Android apk from Unity Application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, manifest

I recently read [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012523/how-to-install-android-apk-from-unity-application/45012767#45012767) and write below code lines for installing .apk file in my unity application :

```
        AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaObject unityContext = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getApplicationContext");

        //Get the package Name
        string packageName = unityContext.Call<string>("getPackageName");
        string authority = packageName + ".fileprovider";

        AndroidJavaClass intentObj = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
        string ACTION_VIEW = intentObj.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW");
        AndroidJavaObject intent = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent", ACTION_VIEW);


        int FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK = intentObj.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK");
        int FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION = intentObj.GetStatic<int>("FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION");

        //File fileObj = new File(String pathname);
        AndroidJavaObject fileObj = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", filePath);
        //FileProvider object that will be used to call it static function
        AndroidJavaClass fileProvider = new AndroidJavaClass("android.support.v4.content.FileProvider");
        //getUriForFile(Context context, String authority, File file)
        AndroidJavaObject uri = fileProvider.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getUriForFile", unityContext, authority, fileObj);

        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setDataAndType", uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("addFlags", FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        currentActivity.Call("startActivity", intent);
```

but after running and call this function my application forced to stop.
here is my Android manifest :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="Store.Narenjgame.store"
    android:versionCode="1.2"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:allowBackup="true">
 
 
     <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="false" />
      </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My android device sdk version is 24.
How can I install apk in unity android application?

Comment: add error log along with your code

Comment: I add try catch to my code , but application stop working and did't catch the exception.

Comment: application is blocking because you are performing long running operation on main thread, Add debugger and check

Comment: Like @Reena said, you should get an exception if you read this from [Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44690501/3785314). I think this a Manifest, provider_paths and android-support-v4.jar  problems. When I first answered this question, it dragged a-along with few other follow up questions from OP before OP solved it.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45095077/3785314) post for how to solve any problem if running API 24 and above. Start reading  from **#1** in the answer.