# Get Android Version Information

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I want to get Android version information from Unity. I know that [`SystemInfo.operatingSystem`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-operatingSystem.html) can be used to do this but it does not have all the information such as release number, code-name and other info.

I decided to make a tiny plugin with Unity's [`AndroidJavaClass`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html) class using Android's [`Build.VERSION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) class but ran into a problem I can't explain.

When I do:

```
AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Build.VERSION");
```

I get class not found exception.

It **works** when use:

```
AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Build$VERSION");
```

Notice that I replaced *"."* with *"$"* and the class can now be found.

I have written many plugins in the past and have never ran into this problem before. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012767/3785314), when I accessed the Android's `Uri` class, I used  `AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");` and it worked. I didn't have to put *"$"* before "`Uri`".

What makes accessing `android.net.Uri` different from accessing `android.os.Build.VERSION`?

Why do you have to put *"$"* between Build and VERSION in order for [`AndroidJavaClass`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaClass.html) to find this class?

By the way, here is the working plugin of [`Build.VERSION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) in Unity:

```
public class AndroidVersion
{
    static AndroidJavaClass versionInfo;

    static AndroidVersion()
    {
        versionInfo = new AndroidJavaClass("android.os.Build$VERSION");
    }

    public static string BASE_OS
    {
        get
        {
            return versionInfo.GetStatic<string>("BASE_OS");
        }
    }

    public static string CODENAME
    {
        get
        {
            return versionInfo.GetStatic<string>("CODENAME");
        }
    }

    public static string INCREMENTAL
    {
        get
        {
            return versionInfo.GetStatic<string>("INCREMENTAL");
        }
    }

    public static int PREVIEW_SDK_INT
    {
        get
        {
            return versionInfo.GetStatic<int>("PREVIEW_SDK_INT");
        }
    }

    public static string RELEASE
    {
        get
        {
            return versionInfo.GetStatic<string>("RELEASE");
        }
    }

    public static string SDK
    {
        get
        {
            return versionInfo.GetStatic<string>("SDK");
        }
    }

    public static int SDK_INT
    {
        get
        {
            return versionInfo.GetStatic<int>("SDK_INT");
        }
    }

    public static string SECURITY_PATCH
    {
        get
        {
            return versionInfo.GetStatic<string>("SECURITY_PATCH");
        }
    }

    public static string ALL_VERSION
    {
        get
        {
            string version = "BASE_OS: " + BASE_OS + "\n";
            version += "CODENAME: " + CODENAME + "\n";
            version += "INCREMENTAL: " + INCREMENTAL + "\n";
            version += "PREVIEW_SDK_INT: " + PREVIEW_SDK_INT + "\n";
            version += "RELEASE: " + RELEASE + "\n";
            version += "SDK: " + SDK + "\n";
            version += "SDK_INT: " + SDK_INT + "\n";
            version += "SECURITY_PATCH: " + SECURITY_PATCH;

            return version;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`android.os.Build$VERSION` itself is an inner class and therefore must append `$` to let the JRE use the dot sign to determine the packages vs. the inner class.

Having it `android.os.Build.VERSION` will mean go to a class called `VERSION` inside `Build` package, whereas `android.os.Build$VERSION` will mean go to an inner class `Version` within the `Build` class inside `os` package

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Does that mean that [`android.net.Uri`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)  is **NOT** an inner class? Since I will be making more plugins in the feature, how do I know if a class is an inner class from the Android documentation?

Comment: Yes, Uri is a completely a separate class, to know an inner class is to either go dig to the source code or just check the name of the class itself. (parent_name).(innner_class_name)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info.