# Why does my build crash when adding the manifest file

Tags: c#, android, apk

Hi I am trying to download and install a apk file with my own unity android application. The only problem I have is when I add the manifest file and build the application it crasht when i build it without it doesn't. The crash is on start up of the application.

I found all code on this link:

[How to install Android apk from code in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012523/how-to-install-android-apk-from-code-in-unity/47678660#47678660)

Comment: y do u need to add a manifest file to the project?  every android project have this file already

Comment: When I dont it doesn't work and in the debugtext I get the message to add the manifest for permission